# The process of task scheduling in cloud

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine, scheduling, cloudsim

What is the right order of scheduling user tasks in cloud data center? is it correct or not?

Cloud provider has a different VM templates. When user requests a services, based on users' requirements, the scheduler will select the suitable VM template for the user then create this VM in host.
Or
the VMs are created in hosts in advance, then the tasks are scheduled on it? 
I am confused about the real process if task scheduling in cloud and what is in CloudSim ? 
I appreciate any help in this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both possible - realtime creation and creation beforehand. Depends on provider, virtualization etc.

Usually orchestration tools are used for managing own hardware resources to offer VM template. Here is Rackspace's [grafana](https://github.com/rackspace-orchestration-templates/grafana) template as example. For OpenStack there is OpenStack Heat, OpenStack Hot and Cloud-Init. You can read here on [OpenStack's doc](https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/openstack-images.html), [another doc](https://docs.openstack.org/developer/heat/template_guide/hot_guide.html), [IBM's description](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-cloud-orchestration-technologies-trs/index.html). When you click via user web UI, it is usually `cloud-init` which does many works. If you install OpenStack as example cloud computing software on your own dedicated servers or own colocation/datacenter, you will use orchestration tools for providing templates. That is case of provider.

If you need to use virtual machines from many data centres, combining many types of providers like HP, IBM, Rackspace, Amazon, Microsoft together then you will use CloudSim like softwares. CloudSim is definitely great open source project, [wiki is here](https://github.com/Cloudslab/cloudsim/wiki/FAQ). There is matter named multi cloud.